# How to swap from XAMPP to cPanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I have a php website that I wrote and is functioning with XAMPP. I would like to transfer this to use cPanel. When using xampp, I had to put all of my files in htdocs folder for it to work properly. What is different now that I am using a different server?

I believe that I have finally figured out what my problem is. I am assuming too much.

When working from xammp in eclipse with localhost/project, if I want to add a file "test.php" I simply add it, save it, and then when I type localhost/project/test.php, there is it. This does not seem to be how cPanel works. Do I need to manually update it somehow? If so, how do I do this?

Also I am using mysite.com/~lamar/test.php which is how it is set up in cPanel. test.php is in S:/Lamar/www/test.php. This may also be the source of my problem.

Any ideas? As of right now I cannot even access any page of my project

Comment: Have you setup your database via the cPanel control panel?

Comment: There is something wrong. The error message says `lamar@localhost`. According to your code it should say `lamar_lamar@localhost`. Can you check this?

Comment: I am equally as confused

Comment: I have set up the database and everything there is working well. I can access everything through phpmyadmin. The problem is that my project is not connecting. This strange error message led me to believe that I had put it in the incorrect file.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your host, you may need to look for a specific folder, although many times you can just put your files in the root directory that you're taken to once you FTP into the system.

If you login and see a `www`, `htdocs`, `public_html`, `httpdocs`, or `html` folder, place your files there.

Answer (score 0):

With CPanel you have to put your files into the `public_html` folder. As said in the comments, depending on your hosts configuration, it might another folder - in your case `www`.

Comment: is that the same as www folder?

Comment: Depending on the configuration `www` may also be correct. Have you tried to put a file there yet?

Comment: I put the file in there and it did show up, but it will not connect to the database. I will edit my question to include this

Comment: Have you changed your database connection string accordingly? The user/password/db params are likely to also be different then on your XAMPP installation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I was having is that Eclipse was not updating to the server. So no matter how much I changed in the files, they were not being reflected on the site. I am using Dream Weaver now instead.